# How to create a custom method for my rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class-method

I have a `Company` model and a `Payment` model.

For my `Company` model I whish to create a custom (class/instance?) method that performs a sumproduct of a selected company's associated attributes.

My `Company`  model:

```
def total_payments
  self.payments.map { |s| s.value * s.currency }.sum
end
```

However if I run `Company.first.total_payments` it gives me a `no_method_error`.

How to I properly define my method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like all good, just reload your rails console. Rails does not apply changes in your classes immediately.

Comment: Yes indeed, you're right. Question: is this called an instance method or a class method? Trying to learn something here :-)

Comment: `total_payments` is an instance method.

Comment: It seems as if I can actually omit calling `self` and just refer to `payments` directly. Is this also your experience?